# Dirac delta integral on the bounded set

Tags: measure-theory, dirac-delta

How to solve that an integral?
$$\int_{[0,10)}x^2 d\mu  $$ where $$\mu = \sum_{k=1}^{4} {{1}\over{k}} \delta_{k}$$
I know that $$\int_{X} {f(x) \delta_{x_0} (dx)}= f(x_{0}) $$ but in that example I don't know how to do it on the interval (0,10]. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I think that you'll get $1^2/1 + 2^2/2 + 3^2/3 + 4^2/4 =10$ since $d$ is linear and the integral is linear

Answer (score 0):

Most likely how you're intended to solve this is to know the following two rules, or at least for them to be "intuitively obvious" to you if you haven't covered them in class specifically:

1. $\int fd\delta_x=f(x)$
2. $\int fd(\sum\lambda_i\mu_i)=\sum\lambda_i\int fd\mu_i$

You can use these rules to work out your integral.

Comment: but these formulas are for integrals over the entire X space, in this example for [0,10) it doesn't  work ..

Comment: @wvnikax Your integral is over the entire measure space $[0, 10)$. Part of the advantage of measure theory is that integrating over a set is the set as integrating over the whole space, fro ma theoretical perspective. Alternatively, if that bothers you, you can replace the integrand with $x^21_{x\in[0,10)}$, so now you're back to an integral over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, is this solution correct? $$\sum^{4}_{k=1} {{{1}\over{k}} {\int_{X} x^{2} 1_{[0,10)}} d\delta_{k}} = 6$$

Comment: I guess I made a mistake and the integral should be 10 right?

Comment: @wvnikax It should be $10$, but other than that you've got it right.

Comment: thanks for help :)